# How to run with various number of user at different times in Jmeter

Tags: multithreading, jmeter, numbers

I want to run login request with different number of users: 10, 20, 30 and generate report with number of users, and response time.

I created CSV file with number of threads: 10, 20, 30

I assigned thread number variable into Number of Thread in Thread group but it does not run.

Comment: seeing plan and code would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use property, call JMeter batch with [different property value](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override), with 10 threads for example

```
jmeter -JthreadNum=10 -t myJmx.jmx
```

And in your Test Plan get the property in your Number of Threads:

```
${__P(threadNum)}
```

Notice that the default of the function is 1 so it'll work (with 1 thread) even if you didn't sent any value.

Other solution to add property file with `threadNum=10` line with calling command line options to either override or add JMeter property file:

> ```
> -p, --propfile <argument>
>     the jmeter property file to use
> -q, --addprop <argument>
>     additional JMeter property file(s)
> ```

In your case, add to command line `-q myprop.properties`

Comment: Thanks, I added jmeter -JthreadNum=10 -t myJmx.jmx  into jmeter.properties but it is still run with default value is 1

Comment: You need to call jmeter **batch**,meaning from the command line with -JthreadNum=10